# How to create two side working navigation property 1:1 in entity framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Person 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }//PK
    
    [Required]
    public Heart Heart { get; set; }
}

public class Heart
{
    public int ID { get; set; }//PK

    public int PersonID { get; set; }//FK
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PersonID))]
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

//Lists for example
var persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person() { ID = 1 });
persons.Add(new Person() { ID = 2});

var hearts = new List<Heart>();
hearts.Add(new Heart() { ID = 1, PersonID = 2 }));
hearts.Add(new Heart() { ID = 2, PersonID = 1 }));
```

So i try to get Heart and i want to include it's navigation property Person.

```
    hearts.Where(h => h.ID == 1).Include(h => h.Person);
    //query generated
    // SELECT * FROM `hearts` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `persons` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`PersonID` = `Extent2`.`ID
    //here we get the correct navigation property heart.PersonID = person.ID which is Person with ID 2;
```

Then i try to get Person and i want to include it's navigation property Heart

```
persons.Where(p => p.ID == 1).Include(p => p.Heart);
//query generated
// SELECT * FROM `persons` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `hearts` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`ID` = `Extent2`.`ID
//here we get wrong result person.ID = heart.ID; we get heart with ID = 1 instead of ID = 2
```

So when i use include it takes the foreign key of the entity i first try to get and when i use include for the navigation property it always compares first entity FK to included entity PK.

I want when i take Person to get the correct Heart.

I'm using Entity framework 6

Comment: Reading this and looking at the code make me wonder how you managed to even run your application. EF should have barfed on this configuration (It does when I use your entities). Can you show more details?

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("persons");
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasKey(p => p.ID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(p => p.ID).HasColumnName("ID").HasColumnType("int").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
                .IsRequired();

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<Heart>().ToTable("hearts");
modelBuilder.Entity<Heart>().HasKey(h => h.ID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Heart>().Property(h => h.ID).HasColumnName("ID").HasColumnType("int").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
                .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Heart>().Property(h => h.PersonID).HasColumnName("PersonID").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();

Comment: this is everything i need to run this

Answer (score 1):

A 1:1 should share the key (in EF) so this would work (using Heart.PersonID as the key):

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace SoAns
{
    /***************************************
    
    Database:

    SELECT * FROM dbo.Persons

        ID
    -----------
    1
    2


    SELECT * FROM dbo.Hearts

    ID          PersonID
    ----------- -----------
    2           1
    1           2

    ***************************************/

    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }//PK
        public Heart Heart { get; set; }
    }

    public class Heart
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }//PK.. in the database, not in the mapping!
        public int PersonID { get; set; } //FK, but this is a 1:1
        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }

    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Heart> Hearts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("persons");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasKey(p => p.ID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(p => p.ID).HasColumnName("ID").HasColumnType("int").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Heart>().ToTable("hearts");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Heart>().HasKey(h => h.PersonID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Heart>().Property(h => h.ID).HasColumnName("ID").HasColumnType("int").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Heart>().Property(h => h.PersonID).HasColumnName("PersonID").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Heart>().HasRequired(h => h.Person).WithOptional(p => p.Heart);
        }

        public Db(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
            this.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var db = new Db(@"Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=PersonHeart;Integrated Security=True");

            var heart = db.Hearts.Where(h => h.ID == 1).Include(h => h.Person).First();
            var person = db.Persons.Where(p => p.ID == 1).Include(p => p.Heart).First();

            Debug.Assert(heart.ID == 1 && heart.PersonID == 2 && heart.Person.ID == 2);
            Debug.Assert(person.ID == 1 && person.Heart.ID == 2);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this will NOT protect you in any way from databases with:

- Multiple Hearts with the same PersonID
- Persons without a corresponding Heart row

To improve your database design a bit, you could:

- Share the key used by Person. (Remove the column ID in Heart and use PersonID as PK and FK)
- Determine the Aggregated root and give that row a unique PK and not-null FK to its dependencies.

BTW: I removed all annotations from the entities in this mapping example.

Comment: I still have the same problem with your answer. var obj = Context.Persons.Where(p => p.ID == 1).Include(p => p.Heart)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        p.ID,
                        p.Heart,
                    })
                    .ToList();

Comment: when i execute this code it compares person.ID to Heart.ID and not person.ID to Heart.PersonID so when i get the heart in the query above i get heart with ID = 1

Comment: the thing is im trying to use EF on already existing app which had 0 navigation properties  which already had the 2 entities so when ppl were creating them they first created person and after some time they added heart  so the PKs are different im not allowed to change the existing records and the way we currently take them is with 2queries var person = Context.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == 1); var heart = var 
 heart Context.Hearts.FirstOrDefault(h => h.PersonID == person?.ID);

Comment: Im currently only using the navigations properties only on the entities who contains the FK because it always compares the FK of the entity we take with the PKs of the included one. So when i get Heart and include Person its correct but not the opposite

Comment: I want to add the navigations properties because it saves a lot of code, less complexity  so its easier to maintain and less queries(faster execution)